# Python: how to prescribe a range to a class variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Need help with this question:

Write classes that satisfy the following specification:

- A Student has a name (an arbitrary string) and a number (an integer in the range 1000-9999).
- Attempting to create a Student object with a number outside of the prescribed range raises an InvalidNumberError.
- Student objects have only one behavior: the string representation of a Student consists of the Student's name, followed by a colon and a space, followed by the Student's number.

How do I prescribe a range to the student number?

Comment: Look up Python classes, the `__init__` method, the `raise` statement, and the `__str__` method.

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0):

Look up python properties: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php

Not only will this check that `number` is valid at instantiation of the `Student`, but will check every time you set `Student.number`:

```
class Student:

    valid_range = range(1000, 10000) # legal values will be 1000-9999

    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.name, self.number)

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number

    @number.setter
    def number(self, number):
        if number in Student.valid_range:
            self._number = number
        else:
            raise ValueError('Student number out of range: {}'.format(number))
```